# OpenGL stereo in layered window

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, windows-7, gdi

Is anybody aware of a way to enable OpenGL stereo while using a layered window in Windows 7?

Comment: Do you have a problem rendering to the left and right buffers on a layered window?

Comment: Yes, windows ignores the right buffer and will only draw from the left buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think the `GL_{LEFT,RIGHT}` are only for output devices that are actually stereoscopic, such as VR goggles, shutter glasses, or layered screens with multiple polarized displays.  Assuming you aren’t using any of these things, you will probably need to make your window twice as wide and use `glViewport()` to draw both aspects of the scene side-by-side.  I’m assuming that your rendering pass is already happening twice for `GL_LEFT` and `GL_RIGHT` buffers, so you should just substitute `glViewport()` calls that target either side of the window in the place of the `glDrawBuffer()` calls.

Comment: I am using the NVIDIA 3D stereo kit with the NVIDIA flicker glasses. In windows that are not layered stereo vision works fine but in a layered window the right buffer is ignored and only the left buffer gets drawn.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL stereo uses the GL_BACK_LEFT and GL_BACK_RIGHT draw buffers, and you should only draw once to each buffer. You also need a Quadro card with quad-buffer stereo support to use this.